# Remove space between percentage symbol and number in Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In Kendo I use `kendo.toString(value, "p0")` to format a string to include a percentage symbol.

`kendo.toString(12, "p0")` renders as 12 %. Is there a way to avoid the space between the number and the percent sign? I would like to render it as 12% instead. 
I can of course take care of it manually, but I was wondering if there is a built in way to prevent manual formatting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like [this](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/EFIb).

```
kendo.format("{0:######.#####%}", 22.33)
```

More info about the format method can be found [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/kendo#methods-format).

Answer (score 3):

The Kendo formats are stored as definitions in the "cultures" object.  The default culture is "en-US" (US English), and you can replace the percentage format used throughout by doing this at document ready time:

```
kendo.cultures["en-US"].numberFormat.percent.pattern = ["-n%", "n%"];
```

I was puzzled about that odd space too, it looks particularly disconcerting in chart axis labels.

Answer (score 2):

```js
kendo.toString(kendo.format('{0:P1}', percentage)).replace(' ','')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in javascript regular expression.

```
var yourstring = "12 %";    
yourstring.replace(/\s+/g,''); // replaces all spaces using regex
```

\s+ means spaces, including multiple spaces in a row

g means as many times as possible in the string

'' is what character you want to replace the space with.  In this case it's nothing ''

Comment: This means handling the problem manually after the fact. I prefer a a solution that let's me use the built in format string. Since it also scales fractions like 0.1 to 10%